# Wordpress: How to use get_page/is_page to display certain pages

Tags: php, wordpress, get

Atm. i'm working on a Wordpress website that requires a bit of rethinking in terms of showing page content.

Atm im using

```
<?php if (is_front_page()) { ?> 
show this content

<?php } elseif (is_page('contact')) { ?>
show this content

<?php } else { ?>
show this content
```

And thats working fine no problem at all. (and i want to keep this for the base structure of the site)

**Basic info:**
- The rule is in the header 
- the rule also defines whether to show a slider or not in the top.
- Allot of content is dynamic in the header

---

The real problem shows later on when i want to code a bit smarter for not having 999999 lines of is_page for every case subpage there is, on the portfolio.

Right now i have to make a line of "is_page" every time i want to create a subpage* and thats very ineffective coding i'd say, allthough the design content requires it to change content depending on where u are on the website.

> The reason why i need to create a new is_page for every subpage is due to the top changes color and different content shows based on the page ur in. the "else" state defines only if i create a new basic page not a case page.

What i want to achieve is if u land on the page "case1" or "case2" etc unlimited number i want to display specific content.

**So**
What im looking for is either a way to create a is_page rule to define if u are on case1-case9999999 show this div

**Or**
Using get_pages to create the rule so i keep using is_page for the base structure of the site and then add a extra rule that controls which content shows on case1-case99999999

If i somehow didn't explain this good enough fire away a comment and i'll do my best to enlight the issue.

Comment: if you have the color changes then try to add custom field for each page and add the color and in front end get the color and apply and for description use the page's editor and add the content of page in it and on front end simply display the content no need of if for each page

Comment: The colors etc. are working the only thing i want to create now is a ruleset that defines if u are in case 1-9999999 then show this content since i have to duplicate the line or the number of pages if i do it the other way around.